# Is it possible for cassandra cqlsh ORDER BY with out using composite and super column?

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

If i am using sing primary key in my table in that situation ORDER BY is possible in cassandra cqlsh query. Is there any solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

*Is it possible for cassandra cqlsh ORDER BY with out using composite and super column?*

--> Yes, provided that you define your "ordering column" as the **first clustering component** (e.g. **second component** of the compound primary key)

Quote from the official doc :

> ORDER BY clauses can select a single column only. That column has to
> be the second column in a compound PRIMARY KEY. This also applies to
> tables with more than two column components in the primary key.
> Ordering can be done in ascending or descending order, default
> ascending, and specified with the ASC or DESC keywords.

This also works when you define your table using the WITH COMPACT STORAGE option (not using composite).

Comment: your correct if my table structure is like is mean CREATE TABLE sample(id varchar PRIMARY KEY  ,name varchar, lanme varchar, time timeuuid) WITH COMPACT STORAGE ; is it possible for order by

Comment: Becouse my erlang client not supported composite column that's why i am trying for query like this, is there any solution without using compound primary key in cassandra cqlsh

Comment: "is there any solution without using compound primary key in cassandra cqlsh" --> No, compound primary key is mandatory if you want to do ORDER BY